# Typing Animation Javascript HTML rotation from array

Tags: javascript, html

I have a typing animation on a html web page. I want to rotate the text in an array but ensure each item in the array stays on the page rather than being deleting before the next one starts.

```js
var TxtRotate = function (el, toRotate, period) {
    this.toRotate = toRotate;
    this.el = el;
    this.loopNum = 0;
    this.period = parseInt(period, 10) || 2000;
    this.txt = '';
    this.tick();
    this.isDeleting = false;
};

TxtRotate.prototype.tick = function () {
    var i = this.loopNum % this.toRotate.length;
    var fullTxt = this.toRotate[i];

    if (this.isDeleting) {
        this.txt = fullTxt.substring(0, this.txt.length - 1);
    } else {
        this.txt = fullTxt.substring(0, this.txt.length + 1);
    }

    this.el.innerHTML = '<span class="wrap">' + this.txt + '</span>';

    var that = this;
    var delta = 300 - Math.random() * 100;

    if (this.isDeleting) { delta /= 2; }

    if (!this.isDeleting && this.txt === fullTxt) {
        delta = this.period;
        this.isDeleting = true;
    } else if (this.isDeleting && this.txt === '') {
        this.isDeleting = false;
        this.loopNum++;
        delta = 500;
    }

    setTimeout(function () {
        that.tick();
    }, delta);
};

window.onload = function () {
    var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('txt-rotate');
    for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
        var toRotate = elements[i].getAttribute('data-rotate');
        var period = elements[i].getAttribute('data-period');
        if (toRotate) {
            new TxtRotate(elements[i], JSON.parse(toRotate), period);
        }
    }
    // INJECT CSS
    var css = document.createElement("style");
    css.type = "text/css";
    css.innerHTML = ".txt-rotate > .wrap { border-right: 0.08em solid #666 }";
    document.body.appendChild(css);
};
```

```html
                        <h1>
                            We develop
                            <span class="txt-rotate"
                                  data-period="2000"
                                  data-rotate='[ "websites.", "databases.", "in HTML and CSS.", "in ASP.NET.", "in C#.", "using Bootstrap."]'></span>
                        </h1>
```

Expected output:

```
We develop websites.
           databases.
           in HTML and CSS.
           in ASP.NET
           in C#.
           using Bootstrap.
```

Each item in the array needs to be typed first before the next one starts being typed.  Once all items have been typed, it needs to stay on the page as a list, the animation should stop and not repeat.

Comment: should stop and don't repeat on what? on the specific word? or stopped and just write *We develop*?

Comment: so if you see on the current code snippet, after it completes the array, it starts again from the beginning. In my case once its typed it all and the output looks like the above. I want it to remain like that and only when the page refreshes, it does the animation again.does that make sense?

Comment: As I understand you need to stop on "We develop using Bootstrap" stop in last message not reloading right?

Comment: Correct. so i need to stop on the last item in. We develop should only be on the page once. The items in data-rotate should appear as a list as the output, it should type each item in the list underneath each other. Once it has typed using Bootstrap, the animation should stop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var TxtRotate = function (el, toRotate, period, fixedText) {
    this.toRotate = toRotate;
    this.el = el;
    this.loopNum = 0;
    this.period = parseInt(period, 10) || 2000;
    this.txt = '';
 this.fixedText=fixedText;
    this.tick();
    this.isDeleting = false;
};

TxtRotate.prototype.tick = function () {
 
 //Stops when text completes
 if(this.loopNum >= this.toRotate.length) return;

    var i = this.loopNum;
    var fullTxt = this.toRotate[i];

 // Get the letter to substring that needs to be appended in the span
    this.txt = fullTxt.substring(0, this.txt.length + 1);
 
 
 if(this.loopNum === 0) {
     this.el.innerHTML = '<span class="wrap">' +this.fixedText+' '+ this.txt + '</span>';
 }else{
 //adds a letter on the screen
 var spacing = '';
 var countSpacing = 0
 while(countSpacing < (this.fixedText.length * 2) + 1) {spacing = spacing+"&nbsp;"; countSpacing++;}
    this.el.innerHTML = '<span class="wrap">' +spacing+ this.txt + '</span>';
 }
    var that = this;
 
 //calculates the time  to wait before writing next letter
    var delta = 300 - Math.random() * 100;

 // If backspacing reduce it by  half
    if (this.isDeleting) { delta /= 2; }

 // If the word is complete
    if (!this.isDeleting && this.txt === fullTxt) {
     //add a delay of 500mx
        delta = 500;
  // add a new line (</br>
        this.el.innerHTML = `<span class="wrap">${this.el.textContent}</br></span>`;
  // add a sibling element to you element
  var next_txt=document.createElement("span");
  // add sibling element to the parent
  this.el.parentNode.appendChild(next_txt);
  
  // make your self new element, so that it writes into the new element next time
  this.el = next_txt;
  //  pick the next word
        this.loopNum++;
  //clear current txt
  this.txt = '';
    }

    setTimeout(function () {
      
        that.tick();
    }, delta);
};

window.onload = function () {
    var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('txt-rotate');
    for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
        var toRotate = elements[i].getAttribute('data-rotate');
        var period = elements[i].getAttribute('data-period');
          var fixedText = elements[i].getAttribute('data-fixed');

        if (toRotate) {
            new TxtRotate(elements[i], JSON.parse(toRotate), period, fixedText);
        }
    }
    // INJECT CSS
    var css = document.createElement("style");
    css.type = "text/css";
    css.innerHTML = ".txt-rotate > .wrap { border-right: 0.08em solid #666 }";
    document.body.appendChild(css);
};
```

```html
<h1>
                            <span class="txt-rotate"
                                  data-period="2000"
          data-fixed="We develop"
                                  data-rotate='[ "websites.", "databases.", "in HTML and CSS.", "in ASP.NET.", "in C#.", "using Bootstrap."]'></span>
                        </h1>
```

See if this is what you want @RA